# When will deprecated classes become unusable?

Tags: android

I want to know when deprecated classes become unusable.
How can I find out about it?
Example, I used below.

```
android.widget.TabHost
androidx.fragment.app.FragmentPagerAdapter
androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTabHost
android.os.AsyncTask
```

Comment: There is no way to know, there isn't a timeline on when or even if deprecated items will be deleted. Most of the time you need deprecated stuff left in to provide backwards compatibility

Comment: Oh, What a hell!!

Comment: There may not be a schedule, but you should generally take the deprecation as a hint that the feature probably isn't the recommended way of doing things any more, and may not get updates, new capabilities, or timely bug fixes.

Answer (score 2):

Framework classes, such as the ones that you cite, cannot be removed without breaking backwards compatibility.

It is entirely possible that at some point Google *will* break backwards compatibility and remove these classes from a future version of Android. IMHO that is unlikely, and if it happens, the community will be very noisy about it, so hopefully you will not miss it.

*Library* classes, such as the `androidx` ones from the Jetpack, can and do get removed from the library in future versions. However, usually, you have some control over when you take on new library versions.